# nHibernate SQL logging + stack trace together

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, log4net, missing-data

I'm having an issue in where records occasionally go missing from our production database.  This is a .NET MVC 2 app with nHibernate.  It has been worked on by several developers over the last few years so we assume somewhere a mapping was set-up incorrectly and that nHibernate believes it should be deleting these records.

I used log4net to log all SQL generated by nHibernate from both our admin and front-end (in seperate files).  Oddly enough it seems the front-end of our site occasionally generates the DELETES for the then missing records.  It's odd because although the front-end and back-end share the same data model the front-end shouldn't have any write/update functionality. We were sure it was a bug in admin where all the CRUD is.  Yet there it is in the logs... a batch of DELETES.

I would like to get more information about where in the stack these SQL statements are being generated from.  If I could somehow get a small stack trace before every nHibernate transaction that would be great.  So far my log4net settings look like this:

```
<appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net" >

    <param name="File" value="nHibernate.txt" />
    <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="yyyy.MM.dd" />

    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
        <conversionPattern value="%d %p %m%n" />
    </layout>

</appender>

<logger name="NHibernate.SQL" additivity="false">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
</logger>
```

Maybe I just need to log the two things separately and compare the times myself?  I'm just looking for a suggestion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `stacktrace` or `stacktracedetail` [conversion patterns](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html).

**stacktrace**

> Used to output the stack trace of the logging event The stack trace
>   level specifier may be enclosed between braces. For example,
>   %stacktrace{level}. If no stack trace level specifier is given then 1
>   is assumed. 
>   Output uses the format: type3.MethodCall3 > type2.MethodCall2 >
>   type1.MethodCall1. 
>   This pattern is not available for Compact Framework assemblies.

**stacktracedetail**

> Used to output the stack trace of the logging event The stack trace
>   level specifier may be enclosed between braces. For example,
>   %stacktracedetail{level}. If no stack trace level specifier is given
>   then 1 is assumed. Output uses the format: type3.MethodCall3(type
>   param,...) > type2.MethodCall2(type param,...) >
>   type1.MethodCall1(type param,...). This pattern is not available for
>   Compact Framework assemblies.

You could use it like this:

```
<conversionPattern value="%d %p %m%n%stacktrace" />
```

---

**Edit:**

Few SO questions on log4net stack trace:
[How do you add a StackTrace to every log call in log4net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606514/add-stacktrace-to-every-log-in-log4net)
[How to log stack trace using log4net (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319810/how-to-log-stack-trace-using-log4net-c)
[Does log4net support including the call stack in a log message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906227/does-log4net-support-including-the-call-stack-in-a-log-message)

Comment: Wow.  Thanks a lot!  I'm just trying it out now.  Currently I'm actually seeing the word "stacktrace" in my logs.  This seems like the right answer though...

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not sure what I missing.  Maybe log5net can't grab the %stacktrace when it's coming from nHibernate.SQL?

Comment: Added few more links that might help. I'm not really sure if stacktrace will work for for non-exception logs.