# How to specify a custom logger into log4net

Tags: .net, log4net

I am interested in implementing the solution for logging as specified here https://stackoverflow.com/a/21944943/529273

What I don't understand, and can't find in the log4net manual is what what to specify in the log4net configuration. In the discussion on that page it suggests

```
<layout type="ScratchPad.CustomPatternLayout,ScratchPad">
<conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %message%newline %type %file %line %method %location %class %stack" />
</layout>
```

What is ScratchPad? Is that the assembly name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The class: ScratchPad.CustomPatternLayout
- The name of the assembly:   ScratchPad

In this case you reference a custom layout class.