# Is there a way to change the default stack trace depth logged by log4net (ILog.Error)?

Tags: c#, log4net

By default only 5 first frames of the calling stack are logged by log4net when using Ilog Error(string message, Exception ex) method.

Is there a way to change it (extend it)?

PS. This is not a duplicate of "Does log4net support including the call stack in a log message". It is not about supporting including call stack in every logged message but it reffers to the amount of stack trace frames being logged **when calling Error(string message, Exception ex) method**.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906227/does-log4net-support-including-the-call-stack-in-a-log-message

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does log4net support including the call stack in a log message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906227/does-log4net-support-including-the-call-stack-in-a-log-message)

Comment: No, this is not related. I explicitely stated that it is about changing the default depth of stack trace being logged when **calling Error(string message, Exception ex) method**. By default it seems to be 5. I need log4net to include more of stack trace in case of logging an Exception.

Answer (score 1):

You have an option to include the callstack in your log message:

> stacktrace:
>
> Used to output the stack trace of the logging event The
>   stack trace level specifier may be enclosed between braces. For
>   example, %stacktrace{level}. If no stack trace level specifier is
>   given then 1 is assumed  Output uses the format: type3.MethodCall3 >
>   type2.MethodCall2 > type1.MethodCall1  This pattern is not available
>   for Compact Framework assemblies.

This way you can include the call stack. I do not know a way of changing the number of frames in the exception. I know it is not limited to 5, it just prints exception ToString(). If you are missing a part of you exception stack, you are probably rethrowing the exception the like `throw ex;` instread of `throw;`